# How can I transform patterns in Illustrator to simulate a perspective?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, texture, cc-2014, perspective

I am using rectangles filled with patterns to create the walls of a room.  I have transformed the rectangles, to simulate perspective, but the patterns do not reflect these transformations - they remain constant.

**The method I am using:**

- I create a rectangle and then fill it with a pattern.
- Then, I choose `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh` (1 row and 1
  column).
- Using the `Free Transform` tool, I click the corner and
  hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> while I
  drag to create the perspective appearance.

As you can see in this picture, the patterns are not being transformed to simulate perspective.

[image]

I used to use this same method, in an earlier version of AI, but now It doesn't work.  I am currently using Adobe Illustrator CC 2014 (trial).

I have also tried Effect 3d / rotate, but it takes time to work and isn't a good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tick the box in the **Preferences** to `Transform Pattern Tiles`

[image]

Then do what you are doing.

Comment: I ticked that box but I still have that problem

Comment: does it work in trial ?

Comment: I found a solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to   Scott answer , I checked **Envelope options**  and ticked the box `Distort Pattern fills`

[image]

Comment: Just a note, that option should be checked **by default**. If it was unchecked, you must have unchecked it at some point.

Comment: @Scott no it was unchecked by default and i don't know in which points.

Answer (score 0):

What I found worked best was to have your pattern filling a normal square, then place your perspective shape on top of that, select them both and go to:
**Object> Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object**

[image]

[image]

Comment: This pattern is not in perspective, though. It is merely skewed. To be in perspective the width of the "bricks" needs to get smaller as the shape recedes towards the vanishing point. But I guess it is OK because the OP mentioned he wanted to "simulate" perspective.

Comment: it was a problem in setting as I Answered :)

Answer (score 0):

May be a bug. Works for me. You need to click the perspective distort to achieve this.
[image]

Comment: this is a new function introduced in the new CC versions.

Comment: Not *really*. Perspective Distort has been there since Illustrator 88. What's new in CC is the *tool* that's all.

Answer (score 0):

After using this method:
"What I found worked best was to have your pattern filling a normal square, then place your perspective shape on top of that, select them both and go to: Object> Envelope Distort > Make with Top Object"

Go to "Envelope options" and select "Distort pattern fills". It makes the pattern  perspective :)

Answer (score 0):

you just have to expand it first. Object > expand

[image]

Make sure the shape is selected first. This makes the pattern transform with the shape.

Comment: Welcome! Can you explain better, for example by adding an screenshot?